# Windows Phone Universal App image zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make my scrollviewer zoom work. Without ZoomMaxFactor and ZoomMinFactor it is working great, but no limits for zoom. 
So i added the properties ZoomMaxMinFactor and my image are resizing without any interaction, i already looked for an answer but got nothing.

My XAML:

```
<PivotItem Header="item 1" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyPanel" Width="360" Height="460">
        <ScrollViewer Width="360" Height="460" ZoomMode="Enabled" 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             MaxZoomFactor="0.5" MinZoomFactor="0.5">
                    <Image x:Name="MyCoolImg"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</PivotItem>
```

And code behind:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyCoolImg.Source = (BitmapImage)e.Parameter;
}
```

Thanks for your time =)

Comment: you set both min and max factor as 0.5.

Comment: Yes, cuz i  want to set the max amount of zoom that users can do . MaxMinFactor should not resize my image, am i right?

Comment: You are setting a fixed size for the image (1/4 of the original size), I think you should set different values for min and max (like 0.8 and 1.2), then user can zoom in & out. I don't know what is the effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,

New XAML:

```
<PivotItem Header="item1" >
     <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <ScrollViewer Width="360" Height="470" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.9" MaxZoomFactor="2.8">
               <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="360" Height="470" x:Name="myCoolImg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </ScrollViewer>
     </Grid>
</PivotItem>
```

Thanks for the help Kennyzx!